# SQL Server Tracking Scheduled Shifts when the day varies

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm not even sure where to start in solving this one, I need to query production data from our MS SQL 2012 Db that has a datetime stamp based on the shift it was recorded in, the tricky part is that we run 4 12hr shifts in a pattern of 2 on, 2 off, 3 on, 2 off i.e. here's the first 3wks of Jan 2013:

```
S   M   T   W   T   F   S
        1   2   3   4   5
        C/D A/B A/B C/D C/D

6   7   8   9   10  11  12
C/D A/B A/B C/D C/D A/B A/B

13  14  15  16  17  18  19
A/B C/D C/D A/B A/B C/D C/D
```

A&C are morning shifts running 7:00-19:00 and B&D are night running 19:00-7:00 I'm fairly new to SQL and haven't had to do anything like this yet, I know I can easily determine the data for the 1/1/2013 AM shift with:

```
select *
from Line05
where L05Time BETWEEN '01/01/2013 07:00' AND '01/01/2013 19:00'
```

for example but I'm not sure how I can tie that to C Shift.

Comment: Can you show how the first 3 weeks of data are stored in the database tables? Having that calendar is nice for the question, but without a better idea of what the tables look like, we can't help much.

Comment: The tables I'd be querying contain only our production line data(WorkOrder#, speed, good count, bad count, Quality %, and so on) and a datetime column that the data was written, there aren't any employees or anything else useful in this situation anywhere else in the Db, I'm going to pursue the suggestion by @jerrylagrou and take a look at our Time & Attendance software Database to see if there's anything that can be used there. I'll also try to post a SQLFiddle with for a table in a bit if you still want some sample data

Comment: SQL Fiddle(table schema with 1 sample Row): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df232/1

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following cranks out a table of shifts.  It isn't exactly clear what you want to do, but you should be able to reverse engineer determining the shift from the date/time of an event using some of the calculations shown here.

**EDIT**: Corrected `case` to handle to 2/2/3/2 pattern.

```
; with Samples as (
  -- Start at the beginning of 2013.
  select Cast( '01-01-2013 00:00' as DateTime ) as Sample
  union all
  -- Add hours up to the desired end date.
  select DateAdd( hour, 1, Sample )
    from Samples
    where Sample <= '2013-01-30'
  ),
  ExtendedSamples as (
  -- Calculate the number of days since the beginning of the first shift on 1/1/2013.
  select Sample, DateDiff( hour, '01-01-2013 07:00', Sample ) / 24 as Days
    from Samples ),
  Shifts as (
  -- Calculate the shifts for each day.
  select *,
    case when ( Days + 1 ) % 9 in ( 0, 1, 4, 5 ) then 'C/D' else 'A/B' end as Shifts
    from ExtendedSamples )
  select *,
    case when DatePart( hour, Sample ) between 7 and 18 then Substring( Shifts, 1, 1 ) else Substring( Shifts, 3, 1 ) end as Shift
    from Shifts
    option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Comment: Thanks! it looks like that will do it

Comment: Actually upon further inspection this doesn't account for the bi-weekly '3 on' days i.e 1/4/13, 1/5/13, 1/6/13 should all be shift C/D instead this is just continuing a 2 on, 2 off.

Comment: @motoxrdr21 - Sorry, I missed that in your question.  The query has been updated to handle the 2/2/3/2 pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that still seems to place the group of three on the wrong dates though (ie the above 1/4, 1/5, & 1/6 are supposed to be C/D instead in the 5th & 6th are C/D and the 6th, 7th & 8th are A/B) I tried tweaking the case when and can't seem to get it to be accurate for more than a week or two, I'm trying to come up with something now that goes based on what Sunday is, the pattern used by our auto-scheduler is shifts alternate weeks working Sun, Wed, & Thurs then the following week Mon, Tues, Fri, & Sat.

Comment: @motoxrdr21 - Okay, now I'm a bit confused.  If the pattern is 2 days on, 2 off, 3 on, 2 off (9 days per cycle) then the same pair of shifts always gets the extra day.  Are you saying the pattern is 2 days on, 2 off, 3 on (7 days per cycle)?  (Makes more sense to have a one week cycle.)  If so, just change the `case` to `case when ( Days + 1 ) % 14 in ( 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10 ) then 'C/D' else 'A/B' end as Shifts`.  (The cycle is really two weeks with a bit of an alternating hobble.)

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thanks! Sorry about the confusion over the length of the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it will get even tricker when there is a holiday or a shutdown occurs.  You are thinking like a programmer, you are thinking there is an algorithm that can determine your answer.  Instead, if would advise that you think like a data-guy.  There should be a source of information somewhere that has the answer you seek.  Ask the person who sets up the schedule if he knows.  There should be a table somewere that tells you what shifts are assigned to what time slots.  Use the data it contains to get your answer.

Comment: It appears the time & attendance tracking software we use auto-generates the schedules it's backed by a SQL 2005 Db that I'm digging through now.