# SQL Server : Tracking Scheduled Shifts Roster when the day varies

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on employees time clocking system and stuck with how I can include the shift cycle so that the system will not issue overtime hours to individual on off duty.

I recently searched and this [SQL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200447/sql-server-tracking-scheduled-shifts-when-the-day-varies?answertab=votes#tab-top) helped a lot but I can't figure out how to manipulate it to run the below shift.

To be more specific:

1. How will SQL determine if employees are off duty or not?
2. Mark individual absent when they are on shift but absent from work?

My shift is:

```
D = Day
N = Night
O = Off
```

**3-2-3**,

and

**2-3-2**

**Shift illustration**

DDDNNOOO and DDNNNOO

Below the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200447/sql-server-tracking-scheduled-shifts-when-the-day-varies?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
;with Samples as (
-- Start at the beginning of 2013.

Select Cast('01-01-2013 00:00'as DateTime)as Sample

Union all
-- Add hours up to the desired end date.

Select DateAdd(hour, 1,Sample)from Samples where Sample <='2013-01-30'),

Extendedsamples as
(

-- Calculate the number of days since the beginning of the first shift on 1/1/2013.

Select Sample,DateDiff(hour,'01-01-2013 07:00',Sample)/ 24 as Days from Samples ),

Shifts as
(

-- Calculate the shifts for each day.
select*,

case when (Days+ 1 )% 14 in( 0, 1, 4, 5,6,9,10 )

then 'C/D' else 'A/B' end as Shifts from ExtendedSamples 

)

select*,

case when DatePart(HOUR,Sample) between 7 and 18 then

Substring( Shifts, 1, 1 )else Substring( Shifts, 3, 1)end as Shift,

Case when DatePart(HOUR,Sample)between 7 and 18 then

'DAY' else 'NIGHT' end as Day_Night

from Shifts

option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Comment: Sounds like you are doing too much in the database.

Comment: I tried to read the question over a couple of times, but I still do not understand what you are asking. You may want to rewrite this question and organize its content more clearly and carefully.

Comment: @KRichard - Yes. His question is not clear.

Comment: How to format code - `select/highlight code with your mouse`, press `ctrl+k`.

Comment: This type of system is *immensely* more easy to write if you do this in a normal programming language, and you create intervals of all the data and slice them together.

Comment: Thanks guys Ive done that as suggested

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen; am using VB.net as the front end and sql 2008 as the back end  and the roster will be created from vb but am looking for a way to manipulate the roster in the database so that I wouldn't have to reprogram the application when there is change of request