# Produce a rolling 4 on/4off shift calendar

Tags: sql-server, date, dynamic, calendar

Looking to produce a dynamic calendar for staffing models for two shifts (Blue team/Red team) that are 4 days on/4 days off.  I'd like to be able to capture future dates and past dates based on a static date.

If, for example, Blue team's first day of their shift is 6/1/2016 and the last day is 6/4/2016, and Red team's first day of their shift is 6/5/2016 and the last day is 6/8/2016, how can I create a rolling view that looks forward and backward in SQL Server?

Essentially I want to know which team is supposed to be staffed for a particular day which will allow me to calculate staffing percentages to look at who's out for vacation/sick/etc.  If I can get the rolling calendar view built, I can use that as my driver to measure staff performance.

Ideally, I'd like to dynamically produce this view:

- Blue team static shift start date - 6/1/2016 06:00:00 AM
- Red team static shift start date - 6/5/2016  06:00:00 AM

Sample output:

```
Shift | Date
Blue  | 5/24/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 5/25/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 5/26/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 5/27/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 5/28/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 5/29/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 5/30/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 5/31/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/1/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/2/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/3/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/4/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 6/5/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 6/6/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 6/7/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | 6/8/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/9/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/10/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/11/2016 06:00:00 AM
Blue  | 6/12/2016 06:00:00 AM
Red   | etc...
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Update**:

Utilizing code from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200447/sql-server-tracking-scheduled-shifts-when-the-day-varies)
I was able to produce to rolling future dates:

```
; with samples as  
(
    -- start with 6/1/2016
    select cast( '06-01-2016 06:00' as datetime ) as sample
    union all
    -- add days up to the desired end date 
    select dateadd( day, 1, sample )
    from samples
    where sample <= '2020-12-31'
),
extendedsamples as  
(
    -- calculate the number of days since the beginning of the first shift on 6/1/2016.
    select 
        sample, datediff( day, '06-01-2016 06:00', sample ) as days
    from samples 
),
shifts as 
(
    -- calculate the shifts for each day.
    select 
        *,
        case when ( days + 1 ) % 8 between 1 and 4 then 'Blue' else 'Red' end as shifts
    from extendedsamples
)
select
    shifts,
    sample
from 
    shifts
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

I now need to figure out how to produce the historical piece to this code so that I can capture previous staffing percentages...

**Update 2:**

So it looks like if I just invert some of the functions and numbers and default to the day before Blue team's static shift of 6/1/2016.  I'm able to produce the historic view as well.

```
; with samples as 
(
     -- start with 5/31/2016 to pull historical.
     select cast( '05-31-2016 06:00' as datetime ) as sample
     union all
     -- subtract days back to the desired start date.
     select dateadd( day, -1, sample )
     from samples
     where sample >= '2015-01-01'
),
extendedsamples as 
(
     -- calculate the number of days before the beginning of the first blue shift on 6/1/2016.
     select sample, datediff( day, '05-31-2016 06:00', sample ) as days
     from samples 
),     
shifts as 
(
    -- calculate the shifts for each day.
    select 
        *,
        case when ( days - 1 ) % 8 between -4 and -1 then 'Red' else 'Blue' end as shifts
    from extendedsamples 
)
select  
    shifts,
    sample
from 
    shifts
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

I can now dump these results in to a static table for reference. Is there a better way to tackle? If not, I'll push on with this and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt Pointed out that I missed a major requirement.  With the help of a UDF to generate Dynamic Date Ranges (listed below), and an "ANCHOR DATE", the methodology wasn't so bad.

> I've tested for random dates, both future and past, and the results seem to hold
>   true.

```
Declare @StartDate  DateTime = '2016-07-15 06:00:00'
Declare @EndDate    DateTime = '2017-12-31 06:00:00'
Declare @AnchorDate DateTime = '2016-06-01 06:00:00'

;with cteBasePos as (Select Date  = RetVal,NegRowNr=0,PosRowNr =  Row_Number() over (Order By RetVal Asc ) From  [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date](@AnchorDate,@EndDate   ,'DD',1) Where @EndDate  >@AnchorDate)
     ,cteBaseNeg as (Select Date  = RetVal,NegRowNr =  Row_Number() over (Order By RetVal Desc)-1,PosRowNr=0 From  [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date](@StartDate ,@AnchorDate,'DD',1) Where @StartDate<@AnchorDate)
     Select Date
           ,Shift = IIF(((RowNr-1)/4) % 2 = 0 ,'Blue','Red')
     From (
             Select Date,RowNr=NegRowNr+4 from cteBaseNeg Where NegRowNr>0
             Union All
             Select Date,RowNr=PosRowNr+0 from cteBasePos
          ) A
     Where Date Between @StartDate and DateAdd(DD,1,@EndDate)
     Order By Date
```

Returns

```
Date                    Shift
2016-05-22 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-05-23 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-05-24 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-05-25 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-05-26 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-05-27 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-05-28 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-05-29 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-05-30 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-05-31 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-01 06:00:00.000 Blue   -- Anchor Date
2016-06-02 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-03 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-04 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-05 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-06 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-07 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-08 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-09 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-10 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-11 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-12 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-13 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-14 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-15 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-16 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-17 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-18 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-19 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-20 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-21 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-22 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-23 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-24 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-25 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-26 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-27 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-28 06:00:00.000 Blue
2016-06-29 06:00:00.000 Red
2016-06-30 06:00:00.000 Red
```

The UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Comment: Thanks John.  Your solution, along with @Matt's has definitely given me some options to consider.  Looking at the UDF approach, if I'm needing to compare a date, from a work order table for example, this could potentially satisfy identifying which shift was working based on the work order date right?

Comment: The UDF is just for Dynamic Date Ranges,  I use it all the time for countless applications.   The cte, which could be a UDF as well could answer the quest who worked on what date(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cteDates AS (
    --put in your desired start date
    SELECT CAST('5/1/2016 06:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME) AS StartDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       StartDate + 1 AS StartDate
    FROM
       cteDates
    WHERE
       StartDate + 1 <= '6/30/2016 06:00:00 AM'
       --put in your desired end date
)

SELECT
    *
    ,CASE
       --just use the beginning day of your known blue shift
       WHEN DATEDIFF(day,'6/1/2016 06:00:00 AM',StartDate) % 8 BETWEEN -4 AND -1 THEN 'Red'
       WHEN StartDate <= '6/1/2016 06:00:00 AM' THEN 'Blue'
       WHEN (ABS(DATEDIFF(day,'6/1/2016 06:00:00 AM',StartDate)) + 1) % 8 BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN 'Blue'
       ELSE 'Red'
    END AS TeamShift
FROM
    cteDates d
```

There is probably some way with Row_Number as in the other answer but you would need to know the starting shift at the earliest date for that type of method to work.  However, you can easily generate your own date table using a recursive cte and then tweaking the formulas you were already working with combine into a case statement.  The trick is that on 0 day 6/1/2016 when counting forward you want days 1 to 4 blue but counting backwards -4 to -1 would be red so you have to account for the shift in logic with a case statement.  And that is one of the areas row_number breasks down too.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I appreciate your response and solution.  It worked like a champ, as did @John's.  There's different ways I can apply these approaches and I've got to now figure out the best route to take.  For clarification purposes, can you explain what the %8 is doing in your Case syntax?

Comment: % is the remainder of division.  so 7/8 gives you remainder of 7.