# SQL Server Create Shift Schedule 4 on 4 off for year with holidays for 4 shifts

Tags: sql, sql-server, schedule

I need to produce a shift schedule , it would nee dot be done each year so I want to script it.

I have 4 shifts, each with their own start stop times (generally same pattern)
Like A / B is 8am to 8pm (4 days on) and then C / D 8pm to 8am 4 days on)
The shifts alternate A/B 4 days and then C / D 4 days .

I know someone has done this but I need help to know how or where to begin with the code.
I know I need a table of shifts with their start and stop times, a table of holidays (maybe - I think there might be something built in to do this).

Then I need the actual table of the schedule .. Shift, Start, Stop , Day/Night, Holiday.
4 days on and 4 days off - if I provide a starting date of December 28th complete schedule by month for a year.

How can I achieve that?

I found this gem to do the annualized yearly day by day , I am guessing I need to look up some math to get it to iterate 4 on 4 off and maybe join two tables

Comment: _perhaps I need a table_ Yes, that actually seems like a good place to start. No one but you knows how your organization operates. Now do we know what "like A / B" means. We don't write code based on "generally same pattern" either. And beware the trap of assuming holidays are the only "non work" days. If your location closes due to an evacuation or weather closure (or other incident) you will appreciate that concept more.  Perhaps start with a search for calendar table.

Comment: @SMor schedule is the schedule (not just for employees) , closures can be handled manually - its 24/7/365  otherwise. The scheduling will still follow the pattern regardless. I should not have used the term LIKE - will change to for example. For scheduling purposes  Holidays are actually work days I just need to identify them. The pattern is the same  A/B  4 on 4 off .. C/D 4 off 4 on. Opposite A/B. I will look up calendaring in sql - thanks for that tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this is a good idea for you to use. Nonetheless, here is a script that will generate a list of shifts while skipping over a list of holidays. While plenty of assumptions are built in it should not be terribly difficult to adapt for similar patterns:

```
with const as (
   select cast('20211228' as date) as basedate, 8 as cycle_length
), holidays as (
    select holiday
    from const cross apply (values
        (datefromparts(year(basedate) + 1,  2, 14)),
        (datefromparts(year(basedate) + 1,  3, 17)),
        (datefromparts(year(basedate) + 1,  7,  4)),
        (datefromparts(year(basedate) + 1, 10, 31)) 
    ) as h(holiday)
), numbers as (
    select n
    from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) as n(n)
), cycles as (
    select cycle.n + (n0.n + 10 * n1.n) * cycle_length as daynum
    from numbers n0 cross join numbers n1 cross join numbers cycle cross join const
    where cycle.n < cycle_length and cycle.n + (n0.n + 10 * n1.n) * cycle_length < 367
)
select schedule_date, description
    from const cross apply cycles cross apply
        (select dateadd(day, daynum, basedate) as dt) d cross apply
        (select count(*) from holidays where holiday <= dt) h(skips) cross apply
        (select n from numbers where n in (1, 2)) s(shift) cross apply
        (values (
                dateadd(day, skips, dt),
                case daynum / (cycle_length / 2) % 2
                    when 0 then case shift when 1 then 'A 8am-8pm' else 'B 8pm-8am' end
                    when 1 then case shift when 1 then 'C 8am-8pm' else 'D 8pm-8am' end
                end
        )) v2(schedule_date, description)
    order by schedule_date;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d03e27163bd37484d2d5c288eb9e80c

Comment: Yes I think that will work enough to get me where I need to be - I have searched the net for some things too and  found this one too .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062789/produce-a-rolling-4-on-4off-shift-calendar a bit more complicate din the things that need to be added (not so self contained in one script )

Comment: @Ken Great! You're right that those other answer look fairly similar.